# Where to start diagnosing a Bryant 926TA error code 3-3 "LIMIT CIRCUIT FAULT"

Tags: hvac, pvc

My furnace was installed in 2019. Since that time, I have occasionally noticed an odd behavior: when there is a large-ish gap between the current temperature and desired temperature (say, overnight I let it get down to 16.5C, and in the morning I have it set to 21C), the furnace will heat for a while (maybe raising to 18.5C), then turn off the heat. The fan will blow for a bit, then the heat will come back on.

I never thought of it as a problem, just "the way the furnace behaves." But today I happened to be in the basement near the furnace when it happened - and the amber status light, usually solid, was blinking 3 times fast and then 3 times slow. The internet tells me the fast blinks are the first number, and the slow blinks are the second number.

> CODE: 3-3.
> RESULT: LIMIT CIRCUIT FAULT
> FIX: Indicates a limit, or flame rollout is open. Blower will run for 4 minutes or until open switch remakes whichever is longer. If open longer than 3 minutes, code changes to lockout #13. If open less than 3 minutes status code #33 continues to flash until blower shuts of Flame rollout switch requires manual reset. Check for:
>
> - Restricted vent
> - Proper vent sizing
> - Loose blower wheel
> - Excessive wind
> - Dirty filter or restricted duct system.
> - Defective blower motor or capacitor.
> - Defective switch or connections.
> - Inadequate combustion air supply (Flame Roll-out Switch open).

The intake/exhaust lines are 2.5" PVC, around 25' with (4) right angle bends and an odd mixture of adaptions to the furnace (see picture). It's a 100k BTU furnace, and according to the manual a 2.5" pipe is sufficient for 110' - so even after accounting for the bends, it should still be plenty long.

There is also liquid dripping from the intake pipe, where it enters the house.

I'm jumping on the intake/exhaust pipes because of the liquid, but also because I noticed the sales contract with the furnace installers stated that they would install 30' of 3" PVC pipes, not re-use the existing ones.

Where should I start debugging this? The furnace seems to work fine otherwise, and yelling at the installers to come back here and install the thing they said they would seems like a really easy options.

[image]